# More tools for reviewing Wiki changes

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits

I have just been reviewing the suggested edits queue and come across this edit to a Wiki post: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17884781

[image]

Now the user that posted the edit seems like they are on the way to adding value to the Wiki tag but it seems unfinished (as indicated by the 'with a' at the end)

There doesn't seem to be any suitable options for rejecting the Edit, there is no option to improve the edit and I don't feel I should approve it as it seems there is some content missing that the author intended to post.

So do we need additional options when reviewing these or what's the best way to deal with this particular case.

If possible I would like to contact the author and inform them that their edit may not have posted completely and request that they update it with what was intended.

Comment: I strongly agree that we need more tools, just ran into the same limitation. Especially for things like spelling or grammar, an _Edit and approve_ button (like with questions) would be really helpful

Comment: Yes, that would be really handy for these cases. I found it strange that the option wasn't available. I didn't feel I had the tools to deal with this particular case

Comment: Those buttons appear when you have full tag-wiki edit privileges which is currently the trusted user privilege (20k on SO). You're *reviewing* the edit, you aren't currently able to *edit it yourself*... So, you can't approve and edit or reject and edit as you can't currently edit it yourself anyway.

Comment: Thank you for the info @JonClements. So when a user with sub 20k rep reaches a case like this we should just skip it?. Maybe wiki edits should only show to those users that have the permissions to deal with the case properly

Comment: I'd say so... it'd give the opportunity for others that can fill it out if needed to do so... However, my gut tells me that's a bad copy/paste from some source and should well be rejected under attribution guidelines instead.